# How to get color from color name in C# compact framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I want to have a list of all colors and when i choose one color I need to get that color from it's name.

I am having list of colors by using this method...

```
    Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
                // We take only static property to avoid properties like Name, IsSystemColor ...
                PropertyInfo[] propInfos = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);

 foreach (var colorInfo in propInfos)
            {
// making a list here
}
```

but I don't know how to get color from it's name as there is no Color.FromName() method available in compact framework.

Comment: please give your code in detail.

Comment: Did you check `Color.FromKnownColor` ? Is this what you need ?

Comment: Has anything more been learned on this question since it was asked?  I'm porting code from a formerly full framework only project and one thing it does is use "Color.FromName(...)" to get colors in a comma separated line of text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the compact framework supports, but in "full" C#, each instance of PropertyInfo has a property "Name" and a method "GetValue" that you could use to find the color given only the name.

Something like (if LINQ is allowed)

```
Color color = (Color)propInfos.Single(pi => pi.Name == colorName).GetValue(null);
```

(Note that `.Single` throws an exception if colorName is not found.)